# Create a DbSet<T> dynamically in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, dbset

In LINQ to SQL, I can create a repository dynamically using `DataContext.GetTable<T>`. Is there a similar way to do this in Entity Framework 4 other than declaring the properties on the specific `DbContext`? For example:

```
public MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MySet> MySets {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to know how can I create/get a reference to `MySets` dynamically as I can with LINQ to SQL as in:

```
var mySet = MyDbContext.GetTable<MySet>();
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`DbContext` has method for this:

```
  var set = context.Set<MyEntity>();
```

Comment: I have used something similar in my project but i encountered a small problem. The DbSet iscreated dynamically and the in-memory graph works nicely; However, when the time comes to store the data into the database e.g. context.SaveChanges() the following exception is throws: Invalid object name 'dbo.CustomModel'.

Comment: Looks like some problem with your mapping because it tries to access db object which doesn't exist

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
DbSet<MyEntity> set = context.Set<MyEntity>();
```

Or, if you can't use the generic method:

```
DbSet set = context.Set(
    typeof( MyEntity )
);
```

Don't worry about second-loading and duplicating a POCO. Sets are cached internally by the Context.

Answer (score 2):

This is my aproach:

```
    public static List<T> GetCollection<T>()
    {
        List<T> lstDynamic = null;

        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            DbSet mySet = db.Set(typeof(T));
            mySet.Load();
            var list = mySet.Local.Cast<T>();

            lstDynamic = list.ToList();
        }
        return lstDynamic;
     }
```

And you call this function as:

```
List<Customer> lst = StaticClass.GetCollection<Customer>();
```

This returns your entire collection. I used this to perform a cache functionality for basic tables which don't change its content very often.